# Question about the Relativization barrier

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, p-vs-np, relativization

Baker, Gill, and Solovay has shown in their famous paper, that there are oracles $A$ and $B$ with $P^A = NP^A$ and $P^B \not= NP^B$. So, one can't solve the $P$ vs. $NP$ Problem
with methods like diagonalization alone.

To find the oracle $A$ is easy. But the construction of oracle $B$ is very
complicated in the paper. Can we use a simpler oracle?

Does anyone tried a $P$-complete oracle? Is $P^P \not= NP^P$?
Would this result be a solution of the $P$ vs. $NP$ Problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $B$ is chosen at random, then $\mathsf{P}^B \neq \mathsf{NP}^B$ almost surely. See for example [lecture notes of Luca Trevisan](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Etrevisan/cs254-14/lecture04.pdf), [Schöning and Pruim's gem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-60322-8_23), or the [original paper of Bennett and Gill](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0210008).

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to find such an oracle that $P^B\not=NP^B$. The set
$ S = \{\langle M, 1^n, 1^t\rangle \mid \exists x\in\{0,1\}^n \text{ with TM }M\text{ accepts }x\text{ within }t\text{ steps}\}$ in $NP$-complete.
We use the oracle $B = \langle M, x, 1^t\rangle \mid M \text{ accepts }x \text{ within }t\text{ steps}\}$. The oracle $B$ is $P$-complete (via logspace reduction).
So, $S^B = NP^B =NP^P$.

If $t$ is very big ($t\to\infty$), then for a fixed $M$ and $x$ there is a $t$ with
$\forall x\in\{0,1\}^n : \langle M, 1^n, 1^t\rangle \in S \iff x\in L(M)$.

Due to Rice's theorem the set $\{x\in\{0,1\}^n\mid x\in L(M)\}$ is undecidable. So, for large $t$ one have to call the oracle $B$ for each $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ in the worst case on a determinstic OTM. This means $2^n$ accesses to the oracle $B$. So, $P^B\not=NP^B$. And $P^P\not=NP^P$, since $B$ is $P$-complete.

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified which notion of P-completeness you mean, but no matter which one, note that every $P$-complete set is in particular in $P$.  The question is thus essentially "given a poly-time oracle $A$, what are $P^A$ and $NP^A$?"

The answer is that these are $P$ and $NP$ respectively.  For any poly-time computable set $A$ there exists a Turing machine $M_A$ that computes it.  Any poly-time oracle Turing machine $M$ will, on input $x$, performs at most $k$ queries to the oracle, say $y_1, \ldots, y_k$.  As $M$ is poly-time, both $k$ and each $|y_i|$ are polynomial in $|x|$.  It follows that the Turing machine $M'$ that simulates $M$ but uses $M_A$ to resolve the oracle queries will take at most polynomial extra time, and thus is itself a poly-time computation.  Hence every $P^A$-computable set is in fact $P$-computable.

A similar argument works for the non-deterministic case; every possible computation path will take at most polynomial extra time, so the computation as a whole will take polynomial extra time as well.